# Elasticsearch docker on travis fails with folder access denied

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, travis-ci

I am having trouble using an Elasticsearch docker image on travis.

Given this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.4.2
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

and the following `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
- docker-compose up -d
- docker-compose logs -f &
- wget -q --waitretry=1 --retry-connrefused -T 10 -O - http://127.0.0.1:9200
[...more stuff here...]
```

The Elasticsearch engine fails to start with the following exception:

```
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-10-19T08:09:23,574][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-10-19T08:09:23,627][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
elasticsearch_1  | org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:256) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  ... 6 more
elasticsearch_1  | Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes
elasticsearch_1  |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:385) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:682) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:789) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:775) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:203) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:274) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:256) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
elasticsearch_1  |  ... 6 more
```

Note the `Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` above. The folder `./elasticsearch/data` exists and seems to be attributed to `travis:travis` as usual.

I need help identifying the root cause here, and to find a solution that hopefully does not involve brute-forcing the permissions using `chown` or `chmod`, and that works on my local machine too (i.e. no hard-coded uids).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue when I realized that my understanding of docker volumes was fundamentally wrong. I thought that in order to persist data, I needed to map the data folder to the local filesystem. But in fact, all that's needed is to map it to a docker data volume! Doing so sidestepped the permission issue altogether.

Before I show the solution, let me just say that I investigated the user mapping issue for the locally-mapped `./elasticsearch/data` folder. Here's what I found: on the travis host, the folder looks like this:

```
$ ls -la ./elasticsearch/data
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 travis travis 4096 Oct 20 18:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 travis travis 4096 Oct 20 18:21 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis    0 Oct 20 18:21 .gitkeep
```

Inside the ES container:

```
elasticsearch_1  | total 8
elasticsearch_1  | drwxrwxr-x 2          2000 2000 4096 Oct 20 18:16 .
elasticsearch_1  | drwxrwxr-x 1 elasticsearch root 4096 Sep 26 14:20 ..
elasticsearch_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1          2000 2000    0 Oct 20 18:16 .gitkeep
```

where `uid` 2000 is the host's `travis` user. Not sure what would have been needed to do since I changed course at this point - other than manually `chown` stuff.

For my case, the better solution was to create a docker data container and map it to the ES data folder. This way, I can rebuild the ES images without losing the data. Here's how the `docker-compose.yml` file changed:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
    volumes:
      - "esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.4.2
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200"
volumes:
  esdata:
```

That's it! The build now works locally and on travis.

Answer (score 2):

Docker containers are always run as `root` user by default. As a result all running processes, shared volumes, folders, files will be owned by `root` user.

If you don't manually create the shared folder, docker will create it and it will be owned by `root` user:

```
$ ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 19 23:02 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 19 21:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  534 Oct 19 21:58 docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Oct 19 23:02 elasticsearch

$ ls -laR elasticsearch
elasticsearch:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Oct 19 23:02 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 19 23:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Oct 19 23:02 data

elasticsearch/data:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 19 23:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 19 23:02 ..
```

That's why you have `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`.

It can be avoided if we create `./elasticsearch/data` folder with permissions of user who starts docker containers before containers are started (before `docker-compose up` command). For your particular case it is:

```
before_install:
- mkdir -p elasticsearch/data
- docker-compose up -d
- docker-compose logs -f &
- wget -q --waitretry=1 --retry-connrefused -T 10 -O - http://127.0.0.1:9200
[...more stuff here...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your investigation and explanation. The folder `./elasticsearch/data` is created in the repo, so it's already there. I added the `mkdir` but it didn't make a diff. You can follow the real-life code here https://github.com/meedan/alegre/tree/travis-docker-compose

Comment: fyi the build works if the volume mapping `./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` is removed from the Compose file. But that doesn't work for me because I need to persist the data locally.